# MySql recorrido de un CURSOR

Tags: mysql

Cómo se realiza el recorrido de un CURSOR en MySql, es decir teniendo el siguiente codigo:

```
DECLARE lc_prod CURSOR FOR
SELECT pedi_prod_clave, prod_descripcion, SUM(vaca_toneladas) vaca_toneladas
FROM   scc_vales_carga, scc_pedidos, scc_productos
WHERE  vaca_tavi_numero = pw_tavi_numero
AND    vaca_eqpr_fecha  = lw_eqpr_fecha
AND    vaca_status     != 'X'
AND    pedi_serie       = vaca_pedi_serie
AND    pedi_numero      = vaca_pedi_numero
AND    prod_clave       = pedi_prod_clave
GROUP BY pedi_prod_clave, prod_descripcion;
```

Se que esta consulta puede regresarme mas de un registro, también se que el recorrido se puede realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
OPEN lc_prod;
get_lc_prod: LOOP
FETCH lc_prod INTO lr_prod_pedi_prod_clave, lr_prod_prod_descripcion, lr_prod_vaca_toneladas;
  IF not_found = 1 THEN
     LEAVE get_lc_prod;
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO scc_t_auxiliar_prod_basc (aupb_prod_clave, aupb_prod_desc, aupb_toneladas)
  VALUES                               (lr_prod_pedi_prod_clave, lr_prod_prod_descripcion, lr_prod_vaca_toneladas); 
END LOOP;
CLOSE lc_prod;
```

La duda es ¿se puede realizar de alguna otra forma ademas de usar FETCH?, esta duda surge por que que pasa cuando en el SELECT del CURSOR van mas de 10-15 campos? En este caso en el FECTH ... INTO declararía los 10-15 campos, ademas que si no me equivoco los campos definidos en el SELECT para ser consultados son los mismos que se pueden poner en el INTO no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la documentación [14.6.6 Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) no parece existir otra manera de recorrer un cursor, solamente [14.6.6.3 Cursor FETCH Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fetch.html).

Además, la consulta del cursor, es decir, el SELECT, debería incluir únicamente aquellas columnas (o campos) que luego realmente serán usados en el FETCH, por ello, si serán usadas o necesitadas 10 ó 15 columnas, luego el FETCH deberá incluir las 10 ó 15 columnas.

Otro punto para reflexionar y tener en cuenta es: cuando realmente usar un cursor. Personalmente, en el caso presentado, no usaría un cursor, directamente ejecutaría un INSERT-SELECT.